# Export command in Windows

Tags: linux, powershell, cmd

I am trying to use the following command in cmd:

```
export PEER=TRUE && python3 -m backend.app
```

and I get this error:

```
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried PowerShell as well and it doesn't recognize the virtual environment.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: If something that works on Linux, MacOS, and Windows would be good, use PowerShell. `$PEER = 'TRUE'; & python3 -m backend.app`

Comment: What does "doesn't recognize the virtual environment" mean? Is there an error message? Has the virtual environment been activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export is a linux bash shell command, the equivalent in windows is set, so:

```
set "PEER=TRUE" && python3 -m backend.app
```

Comment: Better use the recommended syntax `set "var=value"`. Yours sets the variable to `TRUE<space>`.

Comment: That was it ! Thank you man

Comment: if you want to verify that is properly set, you can type on the CMD: `echo %PEER%`

Comment: Doesn't work and echo %anything% prints anything

Comment: I checked it again and its working, the issue was Powershell